# How to perform button animation before performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

In my homescreen, I have a startGame button that when pressed should set off an animation (sender.pulsate()) and then also change viewController:

```
 @IBAction func newGamePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentScore = 0
        timeRemaining = 60
        visualTime = "01:00"

        sender.pulsate()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstLevel")
        self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```

However, the new viewController appears instantly rather than waiting for the Pulsate animation to occur (the pulsate animation does work).

I know this has something to do with the code not being read top down, but what can I add to tell xcode to run one before the other?

Thank you!

ps. this is the pulsate code if its relevant:

```
   func pulsate() {

        let pulse = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        pulse.duration = 0.6
        pulse.fromValue = 0.95
        pulse.toValue = 1.0
        pulse.autoreverses = true
        pulse.repeatCount = 2
        pulse.initialVelocity = 0.5
        pulse.damping = 1.0

        layer.add(pulse, forKey: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation has duration `0.6` seconds. Present ViewController after that time

---

#### Async After

You can create completion for your `pulsate` method which gets executed after your animation ends

```
func pulsate(duration: CFTimeInterval, _ completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    ...
    pulse.duration = duration
    ...
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

---

#### CATransaction's Completion Block

You can create `completion` for your `pulsate` method which gets executed after your `CAAnimation` ends. For this you can use `CATransaction`'s completion block

```
func pulsate(duration: CFTimeInterval, _ completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    ...
    pulse.duration = duration
    ...
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        completion()
    }
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

---

```
sender.pulsate(duration: 0.6) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstLevel")
    self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked!

Answer (score 1):

Just use completion method for our animation, no timer delays.

```
func pulsate() {
    let pulse = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulse.duration = 0.6
    pulse.fromValue = 0.95
    pulse.toValue = 1.0
    pulse.autoreverses = true
    pulse.repeatCount = 2
    pulse.initialVelocity = 0.5
    pulse.damping = 1.0
    layer.add(pulse, forKey: nil)

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        print("animation done")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:        "firstLevel")
    self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work because his `pulsate` method is called on `UIButton` and button can't `present` ViewController

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using `performSelector` also

```
 @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let animationDuration = 0.6
        sender.pulsate(duration:animationDuration)

        //Invoke method after particular delay on current thread

        self.perform(#selector(navigateToViewController), with: nil, afterDelay: animationDuration)
 }

 @objc func navigateToViewController() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewControllerID") as! NewViewController
        self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
 }
```

Pulsate code

```
func pulsate(duration: Double) {

    let pulse = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulse.duration = duration
    pulse.fromValue = 0.95
    pulse.toValue = 1.0
    pulse.autoreverses = true
    pulse.repeatCount = 2
    pulse.initialVelocity = 0.5
    pulse.damping = 1.0

    layer.add(pulse, forKey: nil)   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach with `asyncAfter` with `[weak self]` to remove retain cycle,

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.6) { [weak self] in
    self?.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: what is the retain cycle?

Comment: keeping the strong reference to each other's object, it will lead to memory leak